# R: How to read different files into a two-dim vector?

Tags: r

I have an `R` newbie question about storing data.

I have 3 different files, each of which contains one column. Now I would like to read them into a structure `x` so that `x[1]` is the column of the first file, `x[2]` is the column of the second file, etc. So `x` would be a two-dim vector.

I tried this, but it wants `x[f]` to be a single number rather than a whole vector:

```
files <- c("dir1/data.txt", "dir2b/data.txt", "dir3/data2.txt")
for(f in 1:length(files)) {
  x[f] <- scan(files[f])
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Lists should help. Try

```
 x <- vector(mode="list",length=3)
```

before the loop and then assign as

```
 x[[f]] <- read.table(files[f])
```

I would recommend against `scan`; you should have better luck with `read.table()` and its cousins like `read.csv`.

Once you have `x` filled, you can combine as e.g. via

```
y <- do.call(cbind, x)
```

which applies `cbind` -- a by-column combiner -- to all elements of the list `x`.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that the columns in the different files have different lengths. So the `do.call(cbind, x)` command doesn't work. And without it it seems that I have to access the first column as `x[[1]]$V1`, etc.

Comment: Re the different length: you may need to pass once to get the max length, and the read in a second pass with padding. That would also allow you to return just single columns -- see `help(drop)` for that.